# In Perl, is it appropriate to use map in void context instead of a foreach loop?

Tags: perl, dictionary, foreach

In Perl, if you have a loop like this:

```
foreach (@items) {
    perform_action($_);
}
```

you can replace it with a call to `map` in void context:

```
map {
    perform_action($_)
} @items;
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to doing to? Does it have a performance impact because Perl thinks it has to save the results? Does it improve/worsen readability?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting from Perl [5.8.1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl581delta.html#Miscellaneous-Enhancements) map in void context is not expensive:

> map in void context is no longer
>   expensive. map is now context aware,
>   and will not construct a list if
>   called in void context.

But the postfix form of `for` may be more readable:

```
perform_action($_) for @items;
```

Comment: While the map statement itself might be aware of its context, the programmer might not. From constructs such as `sub foo { map { ... } @_ }` it's not easy to tell what will actually happen and if you're leaking out parts of your implementation while all you wanted to do was to abuse map as a regular for.

Comment: perldoc also says that foreach loop is clearer then map: "Note that $_ is an alias to the list value, so it can be used to modify the elements of the LIST. While this is useful and supported, it can cause bizarre results if the elements of LIST are not variables. Using a regular foreach loop for this purpose would be clearer in most cases. "

Answer (score 15):

The problem with using `map` or `grep` in void context is mainly conceptual.  Both are constructs whose job is to return a list. To discard that list makes for muddled code, unclear on the concept of listops. I never use either of those in void context myself.

I feel the same way about the ternary conditional operator. Its job is to return a value, so using it in void context makes no sense and just confuses people.

That said, I wouldn’t put **too** much stock into `Perl::Critic` or even PBP. I guess it’s better that the book exists than that it doesn’t, but people too often misunderstand the whole point and end up using it as a bludgeon.

Answer (score 3):

I believe 'Perl Best Practices' would recommend using an explicit variable in the `foreach` loop as the best style - it is certainly what I'd use.

```
foreach my $item (@items)
{
    perform_action($item);
}
```

It is an abuse of `map` (or `grep`) to use it in a void context.

Comment: I might say “misunderstand” moreso than “abuse”, but yeah: `for my $item (@items) { act($item) }` is just so much better as not to compare.