# Is using nested map in perl a good practice?

Tags: perl, dictionary, weak-typing

```
my @c= map {
        my $v=$_;
        map {$_ * $v } @m
} @a;
```

Is using `map` like this, a good practice? Why not?
If not, what are other ways?

Comment: don't use `map` like `for-loop`, it is list modifier.

Comment: `map` is not only a list modifier but also a list generator. And that's what his example is showing. Your comment would be correct for things like `map { print } @list`, though.

Comment: @Moritz, "List modifier" is a perfectly applicable term. The list `map` outputs is directly based on the list passed to it. (I agree with the rest, though. Neither `map` is being called in void context.)

Comment: I see lots of comments about `map` in void context, but I'm pretty sure I've read that performance issues in that construct have been fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174537/468327 (p.s. this comment has nothing to do with readability)

Comment: @ikegami ok, granted. I was thinking of the fact that inside the map `$_` is an alias which allows modifying the original list. Meaning `@l = (1, 2); map { $_ += 1 } @l; # @l is now (2, 3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot answer whether or not it is good practice. In general there are a lot of situations in which I use nested maps a lot. It's short, it's concise and to the point.

However, such nested maps are always in danger of growing just slightly too big and unwieldy in which case they become harder to read than they have to (which list does `$_` refer to in which case!?). So use them, yes, but use it with caution -- just like all other similar things that make Perl so terse and expressive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean. It'll work perfectly fine, or are you asking about readability? It can be harder to read a long `map` compared to the equivalent foreach loop.

```
my @c;
for my $v (@a) {
   push @c, map { $_ * $v } @m;
}
```

Comment: How about execution time? Which one is faster, `loop` or `map`? If I am doing huge data processing using perl script, will `loop` slow down the execution? Would `map` be better in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I've always had mixed feelings at the `map` command. There are lots of pitfalls using `map`, and It is one of those things that makes Python people gloat at how unreadable Perl is. Besides, the `map` isn't really all that much more efficient than using a regular loop.

There's a [gotcha](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.118/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ControlStructures/ProhibitMutatingListFunctions.pm) when map modifies the value of `$_`  because it's really just an alias for the value in the original array. Modify `$_`, and you modify your original array. Maybe that's what you want, but the `map` command can obscure that. There's a discussion in [Perl Monks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=743445) about `map`.

Even if your use of `map` within `map` actually works (`map` does localize `$_` for you, so the `$_` in one `map` isn't the same as `$_` in the other `map`), there's the issues of readability and maintainability.

Use `map` only when the usage is clear and easy to understand the context. Save the Clever Perl Tricks for email sigs. I wouldn't use map-within-map.

Comment: I see your point about the perception from python, but I find list comprehensions just as unreadble.

Comment: That "gotcha" also applies to `for`, and all loop-like structures where the list elements are aliased. That's not specific to `map`, but rather, perhaps, to perl. I also disagree that `map` contains pitfalls, perhaps you should validate that statement with some examples.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature! See it's [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)! When you see the word _bizarre_ in documentation to describe a side effect, you have gotchas. When you have to do strange syntactic incantations, so Perl can parse your statement correctly, you have gotchas. Compare map's documentation to the documentation of [Foreach loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops). Besides, the double map will be a maintenance headache. When you have to start thinking like the compiler, you have gotchas.

Comment: The word "bizarre" is qualified with the statement "if the elements of LIST are not variables." The same applies to for loops. Try `perl -e 'print ++$_ for 1,2,3'`. What are these "strange syntactic incantations" that you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Nested `map` has the same problem and the same solution as any other nested structure, except amplified slightly by the need to reassign `$_`.  The fact that a nested `map` doesn't flow as well is a code smell:  your code is trying to tell you that you should structure it slightly differently.

And the appropriate change is to make the inner operation into a function call such that the reader doesn't have to track both scopes at the same time.  In that case, you get:

```
sub scale {
    my ($factor, @numbers) = @_;

    return map { $factor * $_ } @numbers;
}

my @c = map { scale($_, @m) } @a;
```

Comment: There's a lot of setup/teardown here, would you be comfortable with `sub scale { my $factor = shift; return map { $factor * $_ } @_ }` ?

Comment: Sure; that's a pretty much a style question.  I favor consistently using one form or the other unless I've got profiling telling me that the consistency is killing performance, but that's really just me.