# Flatten part of an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

Basically when I use Data::Dumper I get

```
$VAR1 = [
          '63',
          'Joe',
          'Bloggs',
          '8-Mon',
          'FAU70',
          8
        ];
$VAR2 = 'Bye';
```

But what I want to get is

```
$VAR1 = 'Joe Bloggs 8-Mon';
$VAR2 = 'Bye';
```

Any ideas as to how I can process to the array to only contain one value which used to be several values from it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you have the array in variable @array like

```
my @array=(['63','Joe','Bloggs','8-Mon','FAU70',8],'Bye');
```

Dumper on this array structure works like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '63',
          'Joe',
          'Bloggs',
          '8-Mon',
          'FAU70',
          8
        ];
$VAR2 = 'Bye';
```

use this to get what you want:

```
map{$_=join(" ",@$_[1..4]) if(ref $_ eq 'ARRAY');} @array;
```

Now dumper will print like this:

```
$VAR1 = 'Joe Bloggs 8-Mon FAU70';
$VAR2 = 'Bye';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174644/223226 and looping over all elements is not necessary `$_ = join(" ",@$_[1..3]) for $array[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can pick the parts of the array you want using a slice `[1..3]` then `join` them into one string using join like this:

```
my $a = [ '63', 'Joe', 'Bloggs', '8-Mon', 'FAU70', 8 ];
my $var1 = join ' ', @$a[1..3];
my $var2 = 'bye';
print "$var1 $var2\n";
```

Output:

```
Joe Bloggs 8-Mon bye
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of your array references listed as strings, you simply need to convert them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (['63', 'Joe', 'Bloggs', '8-Mon', 'FAU70', 8], 'Bye');

print Dumper(map {ref $_ ? "@$_" : $_} @array);
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = '63 Joe Bloggs 8-Mon FAU70 8';
$VAR2 = 'Bye';
```

However, I would suggest looking into [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) as an alternative to [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) if your goal is just tighter output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (['63', 'Joe', 'Bloggs', '8-Mon', 'FAU70', 8], 'Bye');

use Data::Dump;
dd @array;
```

Outputs:

```
([63, "Joe", "Bloggs", "8-Mon", "FAU70", 8], "Bye")
```