# Loop through file in perl and remove strings with less than 4 characters

Tags: perl

I am trying to bring a file loop through it and remove any strings that have less than four characters in it and then print the list. I come from a javascript world and perl is brand new to me.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 


sub lessThan4 { 
  open( FILE, "<names.txt" ); 
  my @LINES = <FILE>; 
  close( FILE ); 
  open( FILE, ">names.txt" ); 

  foreach my $LINE ( @LINES ) { 
    print FILE $LINE unless ( $LINE.length() < 4 ); 
  } 

  close( FILE ); 
}
```

Comment: Line length or strings?  Line length as a one liner is `perl -ne 'print unless length > 4;' names.txt` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
# automatically throw exception if open() fails
use autodie;

sub lessThan4 {

  my @LINES = do {
    # modern perl uses lexical, and three arg open
    open(my $FILE, "<", "names.txt"); 
    <$FILE>; 
  };
  # remove newlines
  chomp(@LINES);

  open(my $FILE, ">", "names.txt"); 

  foreach my $LINE ( @LINES ) { 
    print $FILE "$LINE\n" unless length($LINE) < 4;
    # possible alternative to 'unless'
    # print $FILE "$LINE\n" if length($LINE) >= 4;
  }

  close($FILE); 
}
```

Comment: One-liner using in place edit, `perl -i -lne 'length <4 or print' names.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You're basically there. I hope you'll find some comments on your code useful.

```
# Well done for including these. So many new Perl users don't
use strict; 
use warnings; 

# Perl programs traditionally use all lower-case subroutine names
sub lessThan4 { 
  # 1/ You should use lexical variables for filehandles
  # 2/ You should use the three-argument version of open()
  # 3/ You should always check the return value from open()
  open( FILE, "<names.txt" ); 

  # Upper-case variable names in Perl are assumed to be global variables.
  # This is a lexical variable, so name it using lower case.
  my @LINES = <FILE>; 
  close( FILE ); 

  # Same problems with open() here.
  open( FILE, ">names.txt" ); 

  foreach my $LINE ( @LINES ) { 
    # This is your biggest problem. Perl doesn't yet embrace the idea of
    # calling methods to get properties of a variable. You need to call
    # length() as a function.
    print FILE $LINE unless ( $LINE.length() < 4 ); 
  } 

  close( FILE ); 
}
```

Rewriting to take all that into account, we get the following:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

sub less_than_4 {
  open( my $in_file_h, '<', 'names.txt' ) or die "Can't open file: $!"; 
  my @lines = <$in_file_h>; 
  close( $in_file_h ); 
  open( my $out_file_h, '>', 'names.txt' ) or die "Can't open file: $!";

  foreach my $line ( @lines ) { 
    # Note: $line will include the newline character, so you might need
    # to increase 4 to 5 here
    print $out_file_h $line unless length $line < 4; 
  } 

  close( $out_file_h ); 
}
```

Comment: In 5 years using Stackoverflow have I never received such a caring response. Thank you for your comments for a perl newbie.

Comment: Dave Cross the above does not print anything. I did call less_than_4() method at top of file.

Comment: Looks like last print has something missing.

Comment: Yeah. I've edited my answer to remove the extra bracket I left at the end of the `unless` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to bring a file loop through it and remove **any strings that have less than four characters** in it and then **print the list**.

I suppose you need to remove strings from the file which are less than 4 chars in length.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open ($FH, "<", "names.txt");
my @final_list;

while (my $line = <$FH>) {

    map {
        length($_) > 4 and push (@final_list, $_) ;
    } split (/\s/, $line);

}

print "\nWords with more than 4 chars: @final_list\n";
```

Comment: `push @final_list, grep { length($_) >4 } split (/\s/, $line);` instead of `map` in [void context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4174644/223226).

Answer (score -2):

```
#Please try this one:
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my @new;
while(<DATA>)
{

#Push all the values less than 4 characters

    push(@new, $_) unless(length($_) > '4');
}
print @new;

__DATA__
Williams
John
Joe
Lee
Albert
Francis
Sun
```

Comment: ... **remove** *any strings that have less than four characters*

Comment: @RobEarl: I updated '>' instead of '<' delimeter. I am newbie to this blog. Could you please explain whats my mistake on the above said code and encourage to improve my knowledge pls.

Comment: You're removing anything which is *more than* 4 characters