# extracting hex values from line in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string like this, I need to extract only the hex values from line then copy the hex values in new file.

Input line in file:

```
ame (header(...))  0x0D 0x0C 0x4A 0x00 0x01 0x00, 0x02 0x00, 0x0A 0x00,  
0x04 0x00, 0x04 0x05 0x00 0x001f 0x001f 0x007f 0x00, 0x002b 0x007f 0x0000
0x00 0x0000 0xffffffaf 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00, 
(non_t_crmax 0x0D 0x00,  TDD 0x5D 0x2760 Invalid 0x0000 0x02 0x00, 
(rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type
```

Expected output:

```
0x0D, 0x0C, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 
0x04, 0x05,0x00, 0x001f, 0x001f, 0x007f, 0x00, 0x002b, 0x007f, 0x0000, 0x00 
0x0000, 0xffffffaf,0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x0D, 
0x00,0x5D 0x2760 0x0000 0x02 ,0x00,
```

Comment: `my @hex = $line =~ /(0x[0-9A-F]+)/ig;`

Comment: in your expected output, the commas and spaces aren't consistent.  is that an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple perl script (with comments), parsing input and output what do you need.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# buffer creation, will contain all desired values
my @buf;

# main loop from stdin
while (<>) {


      # 2. push value in @buf if match desired regrex
  map({ push(@buf,$_) if $_ =~ /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i}
      # 1. split every line on null char
      split(/\s+/, $_));
} 

# print comma separated result
print join(",", @buf)."\n";
```

Example:

```sh
chmod +x script.pl
cat data | ./script.pl
mycoolcommand | ./script.pl
```

Output:

```
0x0D,0x0C,0x4A,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x0A,0x04,0x04,0x05,0x00,0x001f,0x001f,0x007f,0x002b,0x007f,0x0000,0x00,0x0000,0xffffffaf,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x0D,0x5D,0x2760,0x0000,0x02
```

Comment: Better you should have used `grep` instead of `map`.

Comment: `map` seems more malleable and extensible than `grep`, but could give me an example? :)

Comment: I believe both `map` and `grep` are  *malleable* and *extensible* based on their place of use. Here for example:  `map({ push(@buf,$_) if $_ =~ /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i} split(/\s+/, $_));` can be replaced with `my @buf = grep { /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i } split(/\s+/, $_)`

Comment: @MathieuK: `map` used in void context is always a code smell and should usually be replaced with a `foreach` loop. To use `map` as intended (i.e. to transform a list) your code should be rewritten as `@buf = map { /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i ? $_ : () } split`. But as @AruneshSingh says, to filter a list (as you are doing here), `grep` should be your tool of choice. (Also worth mentioning that `split()` with no arguments is the same as `split(/\s+/, $_)`.)

Comment: Thanks for these advises! @DaveCross: your snippet is clear and pretty  elegant!

Comment: Some [more discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174492/in-perl-is-it-appropriate-to-use-map-in-void-context-instead-of-a-foreach-loop) on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = << 'DATA'; # this is what you read from your file
ame (header(...))  0x0D 0x0C 0x4A 0x00 0x01 0x00, 0x02 0x00, 0x0A 0x00,  
0x04 0x00, 0x04 0x05 0x00 0x001f 0x001f 0x007f 0x00, 0x002b 0x007f 0x0000
0x00 0x0000 0xffffffaf 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00, 
(non_t_crmax 0x0D 0x00,  TDD 0x5D 0x2760 Invalid 0x0000 0x02 0x00, 
(rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type (rat_type
DATA

my @hexvals = $input =~ /(0x[\da-f]+)/ig;

print join ', ', @hexvals; # output
```

Output:

```
0x0D, 0x0C, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00,
0x04, 0x05, 0x00, 0x001f, 0x001f, 0x007f, 0x00, 0x002b, 0x007f, 0x0000,
0x00, 0x0000, 0xffffffaf, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
0x0D, 0x00, 0x5D, 0x2760, 0x0000, 0x02, 0x00
```

Comment: if the value is more than 1 byte(0x002b and 0xffffffaf ) then I need to split with  0x00,0x2b and 0xff,0xff, 0xff, 0xaf  how to do this

Comment: @Abhishek: This is a different question. Please put it in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers you have so far are correct, but they seem to make things far harder than necessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @hex;
push @hex, /(0x[0-9a-f]+)/ig while <>;

$" = ',';
say "@hex";
```

This is written as a Unix filter (so much more flexible than hard-coding filenames) so it reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. Call it like this:

```
$ ./extract_hex < your_input_txt
```

It's actually possible to simplify even further and lose the intermediate `@hex` array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

say join ',', map { /(0x[0-9a-f]+)/ig } <>;
```

But that might be a little too terse for many people :-)

Comment: Re "*but they seem to make things far harder than necessary.*", That's virtually identical Inferno's answer, 4 hours earlier. The difference is that you use `$"` (without localizing it at that), which is awful enough for a downvote as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want, where $input_filename is the name/path of the file the data is in, and $output_filename is the name/path of the file you want to write the data to.  Always remember to use strict; and use warnings;

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

# Enforce good programming
use strict;
use warnings;

# Name of the file the data is in
my $input_filename  = 'input.txt';

# Name of the file you want to dump the output to
my $output_filename = 'output.txt';

# Open the file
open my $input_fh, "<", $input_filename or die $!;

# Array to store the hex data
my @hex_array;

# Loop over each of the lines of the file
while (my $line = <$input_fh>){
    # Find all the matches and push them to the array
    while ($line =~ m/(0x(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi){
        push @hex_array, $1;
    }
}

# Close the file
close $input_fh;

# Open the output file
open my $output_fh, ">", $output_filename or die $!;

# Write the data to the file
print {$output_fh} join(", ", @hex_array);

# Close the file
close $output_fh;

# Exit
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I want add little more information I want extract the decimal value started with only for this braces {1}  e.g.1.  pccpch_rscp -47Sint8,signed char .  2.fail_ind SUCCESS { 1}  I was trying with m/(0x(\-d+)(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi ..but it did not work for me .could you please help me

Comment: @Abhishek: That sounds like you're asking a completely new question. Probably best to post that separately.